# How is the initialization of x.a is considered in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, attributes

Here there is no attribute called "a" in the class Node then what is the meaning of x.a ? Can object name contain the character "." in python ?

```
class Node :
  def __init__(self, left = None, data = None, right = None) :
    self.left = left
    self.data = data
    self.right = right
x = Node(50)
x.a = Node(40)
```

Comment: You are simply mistaken about where attributes are allowed to be assigned. In Python, by default, an instance of a user-defined class can accept any attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a **Dynamically Typed** Language. Which means you can **set the value** of any *variable* without having to **declare** that *variable*.

In your code snippet, `x = Node(50)` is creating a new node class object with `x.left` assigned to **50.**

Now by doing `x.a = Node(40)`, we are just defining a new **attribute** of the object `x` with name `a`, which will be a Node class object with `left` value of **50**.

If you do `dir(x)` it will give you something like this,

```py
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',

  #Some other attributes
 
'__weakref__',
 'a',
 'data',
 'left',
 'right']
```

If you take a look at the last 4 attributes you can see that `a` is now also added as an ***attribute*** of the x object.

#### Conclution

if you do `x.new_attribute = Node(10,20,30)` when `new_attribute` isn't present in the object then python will just create a **new** **attribute** inside the `x` object with the name `new_attribute` & assign it the value of `Node(10,20,30)`.

Comment: Ok I understood. But what happens if I put x.a.b = Node(10). Will it be considered as (x.a).b or something else ? What happens if we keep on doing this x.a.b.c.d.e = Node(5) ?

Comment: x.n.m is possible as long as x.n is a class object. x.a.b.c.d.e will work if x.a.b.c.d is object of some class. This will not work if the parent element is an non-class object, lets say integer. If x.p.q = 25 then x.p.q.r will give error.